# Regex find every occurence of string and it must be always followed by the same string

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a string and it contains several "value=[something]" parts. I need to write a regex (PCRE) that will succeed only if "value" has always the same value. For example in the string "value=" occurs n times and if the value is always "cat", then succeed, but fail if it finds something else than "cat".

My attempts failed so far writing a regex. My approach is to capture the first value of "value=" then somehow match on all the other "value="s, but I can't seem to find a working method.
Of course I can't know what the value will be, this is why I have to capture it.

Must succeed:

```
aaaaaaa bbbbb value=cat cccccc ddddd value=cat fffffff value=cat ggggg hh jjj value=cat kkkkk
```

Must fail:

```
aaaaaaa bbbbb value=cat cccccc ddddd value=cat fffffff value=bat ggggg hh jjj value=cat kkkkk
```

Sorry for overcomplicated explaining.

Edit: probably I should have mention this already, but I am limited what I can use. In this custom environment I cannot use anything else besides PCRE, and even that has some custom limitations, for example I can't use conditional groups.

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Might be another approach?

Comment: I am using the regex in the custom environment of a tool of our company, and unfortunately limitations apply... In the system I want to use this, I cannot use anything else, only (limited) PCRE. For example I cannot use conditional groups. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an *if statement* you can match such input strings. The idea is, if first group contains something it should match the same value in `\1` after consuming a `value=` string otherwise (if is first occurrence) it matches and captures right side of equation as the first group.

RegEx:

```
^(?:(?!value).|value=(?(1)\1(?!\S)|(\S++)))++$
```

*Note: if multiple lines are supposed to be passed as input, `m` modifier should be set.*

[**Live demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/oFjrcW/6)

Explanation:

```
^               # Assert beginning of line
(?:             # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    (?!value).      # If we are not hitting a `value=...` token, consume one character
    |               # Else
    value=          # Match `value=`
    (?(1)           # If first capturing group is set
        \1(?!\S)        # Next characters should be a back-reference to it
        |               # Else
        (\S++)          # Capture its value for the first time
    )               # End of if conditional
)++             # As much as possible (possessively) - non-empty line, end of non-capturing group (a)
$               # Assert end of line
```

---

If `value` part is real or if a similar word is going to be used instead, an approach like below one is almost much faster, talking performance-wise:

```
^(?:[^v\v]+(?!value).|value=(?(1)\1(?!\S)|(\S++)))++$
```

Comment: This could be the best solution, if I was allowed to use conditional groups in our environment. Sorry for not including that in my initial post.:( Your solution is great!

Comment: I chose your answer as the solution, because this brought me the closest to what I have finally created. This is it:

Comment: ^(?=.+?value=(\S{1,128}).+?value=)(?:(?!value=).|value=\1)+$

Answer (score 2):

Not a pure regex solution but might be useful as a workaround

```
$ grep -oE 'value=\w+' pass | uniq | awk 'END{exit NR>1?1:0}'; echo $?
0

$ grep -oE 'value=\w+' fail | uniq | awk 'END{exit NR>1?1:0}'; echo $?
1
```

used your sample input for pass and fail files.

```
$ head pass fail
==> pass <==
aaaaaaa bbbbb value=cat cccccc ddddd value=cat fffffff value=cat ggggg hh jjj value=cat kkkkk

==> fail <==
aaaaaa bbbbb value=cat cccccc ddddd value=cat fffffff value=bat ggggg hh jjj value=cat kkkkk
```

perhaps better without uniq

```
$ grep ... | awk 'a[$0]++>1{exit 1}'
```

Comment: Hey, thank, looks like a nice solution, but unfortunately I am limited only to regex (see my comment to my own post).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (a very long an ugly one)

```
^(?:[^v]|v(?!a)|va(?!l)|val(?!u)|valu(?!e)|value(?!=))*value=(\S+)((?:[^v]|v(?!a)|va(?!l)|val(?!u)|valu(?!e)|value(?!=))*value=(\1))*(?:[^v]|v(?!a)|va(?!l)|val(?!u)|valu(?!e)|value(?!=))*$
```

The crucial part of the solution is a sub-expression repeated three times for trapping `value=`:

```
(?:[^v]|v(?!a)|va(?!l)|val(?!u)|valu(?!e)|value(?!=))
```

This allows us to place `^` and `$` anchors to trap invalid input before or after the matching portion of the pattern.

The heart of the match is capturing `(\S+)` after the first match of `value=`, and then using that capture as `(\1)` in subsequent matches.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/lwWU6n/1)

Comment: Ugly, but so far this seems to be the only solution I can actually use in my environment. I will probably go with this, so thank you!

Comment: Looks like I cannot use this ugly but working solution, because the number of repeats are limited in our system. Probably I will be able to come up with something that I learned from your and from revo's solution, I will check back later with the result!

Comment: @Tom You can probably combine this with revo's solution like this: `^(?:(?!value).)*value=(\S+)((?:(?!value).)*value=(\1))*(?:(?!value).)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/YaeerH/2)).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on ES6fiddle.net.  It's not very elegant, but it sure gets the job done.  Good Luck!

```
let arr = "aaaaaaa bbbbb value=cat cccccc ddddd value=cat fffffff value=cat ggggg hh jjj value=cat kkkkk".toLowerCase().split(" ").sort();

function vKeeper(e,i,a){
    if(a[i].charAt(0) !== "v"){
         a[i] = "";
    }
}
function vStripper(e,i,a){
    a[i] = a[i].replace("value=",""); 
}


arr.forEach(vKeeper);

arr.forEach(vStripper);


while(arr[0] === ""){
    arr.shift(); 
}

var res = false;

while(arr[0] === arr[arr.length-1]){

  if(arr.length === 1){

    res = true
    break;
  } else {

        arr.pop()
  }
}

console.log(res);
```